# Extrude lines from a circle

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to extrude lines from a circle with controllable height of the lines like this [image: this]

(Sorry for my bad paint-skills)

And I was wondering what method I should use to accomplish this? As I said I would want to be able to set the line-height of each individual line, but they should all come from the circle.

Another thing to note is that the height of each line will be updated quite frequently, so a fast method would also be good.

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Ok so I tried using the Polar to Cartesian method. But the lines doesn't seem to get placed in an even fashion. Instead the look like this (notice bottom left-ish)

[image]

Here's the function I wrote. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void DrawLines()
    {
        double circleRadius = ellipse.Height / 2;
        int count = 10; // number of lines
        double angleBetween = 360 / count;
        double offset = 100 + circleRadius; // 100 is the margin from left and top in its parent Grid.
        Random random = new Random();


        for (double angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += angleBetween)
        {
            double height = random.Next(20, 40);

            double xStartPos = offset + (Math.Cos(angle) * (circleRadius));
            double yStartPos = offset + (Math.Sin(angle) * (circleRadius));

            double xEndPos = offset + (Math.Cos(angle) * (circleRadius + height));
            double yEndPos = offset + (Math.Sin(angle) * (circleRadius + height));


            Line line = new Line();

            line.X1 = xStartPos;
            line.Y1 = yStartPos;

            line.X2 = xEndPos;
            line.Y2 = yEndPos;

            line.StrokeThickness = 3;
            line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));

            lines.Add(line); // adding lines to a list so I can change the height later.

            container.Children.Add(line); // adding to the parent grid
        }

    }
```

Comment: you need some background like this? or a control? I mean what is exactly the ***circle*** you mean here.

Comment: What code do you already have to draw the circle? Is it simply a bitmap, or do you know the actual geometry of it? If the latter, then this is a simple matter of using y = mx + b to calculate the end points of the line segments, where you calculate m based on the circle's center and the starting point of the line. The starting points are simply points around the circle, which are easily calculated using trigonometry. If you want it to be faster, cache the starting points and m, and just compute the end points based on the "height" (length) of each line.

Comment: Figuring out the endpoints of the lines is pretty simple if you convert from [polar coordinates](http://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html).

Comment: @MikeStrobel I tried your method but I ran into a problem. Check the edited post

Comment: Can you change the circle's `Opacity` to `0.5` and post an updated screenshot?

Comment: @MikeStrobel There you go. None of the lines seem to be inside the ellipse.

Comment: That image provider seems to be blocked at my office.  Can you attach it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

```
double angleBetween = 360 / count;
```

You are doing an integer division there. Works for 10 lines, but you should use double division.

And (probably) the real issue:

```
for (double angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += angleBetween)
{
    double xStartPos = offset + (Math.Cos(angle) * (circleRadius));
```

Math.Cos expects radians, but you provide degrees. Astonishing, that it is only *a bit* off.

Try it like this:

```
public void DrawLines()
{
    double circleRadius = ellipse.Height / 2;
    int count = 10; // number of lines
    double angleBetween = 2 * Math.PI / count;
    double offset = 100 + circleRadius; // 100 is the margin from left and top in its parent Grid.
    Random random = new Random();


    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        double angle = i * angleBetween;
        double height = random.Next(20, 40);

        double xStartPos = offset + (Math.Cos(angle) * (circleRadius));
        double yStartPos = offset + (Math.Sin(angle) * (circleRadius));
```

Comment: Excellent!! Did not know about the Sin/Cos functions. Haven't used them much enough I guess. I edited my function to use 2 * pi (tau) and it works as it should. Thank you very much =)

Comment: One small addition: Do not use the angle directly in the loop condition. Due to floating point roundoff errors, 10 * angleBetween may be smaller than 2*Pi.